# from object_detection import model_lib_v2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: tensorflow

python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo3tt.png)

how to solved problem?

Comment: This error results from that either you did not install the object_detection library or you don't have a python file named object_detection in the directory where you ran the script.

Comment: I want to perform model training using tensorflow api. My object_detection file exists in my project directory. I guess I shouldn't be using the Python global scope. I'm new to this stuff. I do not have too much information. I cannot perform model training because I am encountering this error. :(

Here is the link of the tutorial video I watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco 
My file directory is as in this video.

I have done all the necessary installations.

I tried giving the object_detection path to the PYTHONPATH to resolve my error but it didn't work.

Comment: I suggest you check out these two links: 1. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md 2. https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-the-colab-sample-notebooks-477707fadf1b

Comment: Thank you. I will review the links you sent and try again.